# Is possible to make login in Azure behind the scenes

Tags: php, angular, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am working on one project in *Angular* and *PHP*, I want to make login on Azure using **ADAL** (**Azure Active Directory Library**). 
It is possible to do that without popup login Microsoft something like pass only username and password or client secret and to get the token for future request?

Comment: There are flows where user doesn't need to be prompted for credentials which can be implemented with Azure AD and ADAL.. but you need to provide more details.. like what are you trying to authenticate to? Is it that you're looking to get a token for future call to Microsoft Graph? Do you need to make calls using permissions of user or working under application permissions like a daemon is good? What does your code to acquire token look like right now (something that you have tried and isn't working)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Azure authenticates external websites is through OAuth 2.0 which requires the user to login to their account on the Azure servers and then give your website authorization code so that you can request an access token to complete the OAuth flow.

It isn't secure to capture the user's Username and Password on your website and then send through to Azure, therefore they do not let you do that.

More explanation of the oAuth flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code